# Pesaran CD test on panel data

Tags: r, panel, plm

I am trying to do the Pesaran CD Test on some panel data on Italian Provinces. For each unit I have 22 years, each one splitted in quarters (so 92 observation for each unit).

The variable "lag_lingua" has the same value for each quarters and years for one province, but it chagnes among provinces.

This is the code that I use:

```
library(plm)

A <- data[-2]

AA <- pdata.frame(A, index = c("id","time"))

pcdtest(AA$lag_lingua)
```

I get this result:

```
Pesaran CD test for cross-sectional dependence in panels
data: 

AA$lag_lingua

z = NA, p-value = NA

alternative hypothesis: cross-sectional dependence

Warning message:

In cor(wideres, use = "pairwise.complete.obs") :

la deviazione standard è zero.
```

I can imagine that this is due to the fact that the variable changes only between units and not "inside" them, but how can I solve this problem and test for CD?

[image]

Comment: can you please provide `data` object so we can run your code

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about the variable being time-constant (varies only over units) is correct. The test uses correlation between the units and if these are constant, correlation is not defined, hence the test returns `NA`.

To illustrate, let's create a non-time varying variable called `var` and run the test:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")

# create time-constant variable 'var' which varies per individual but not over time    
Grunfeld$var <- Grunfeld$firm
pGrun <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld)

pcdtest(pGrun$var) # same as pcdtest(var ~ 1, data = pGrun)
#> Warning in cor(wideres, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"): the standard deviation
#> is zero
#> 
#>  Pesaran CD test for cross-sectional dependence in panels
#> 
#> data:  pGrun$var
#> z = NA, p-value = NA
#> alternative hypothesis: cross-sectional dependence

# can check for variation across unit and time with pvar():
pvar(pGrun$var)
#> no time variation:       var
```

All test methods in `pcdtest` are based on the correlation between observations of the various units (rho). So, basically, calling `cor()` with input of several pairs of constant vectors, so something like this:

```
cor(c(1, 1), c(2, 2))
#> Warning in cor(c(1, 1), c(2, 2)): the standard deviation is zero
#> [1] NA
```

We see `NA` and the warning as in `pcdtest` with the plain `cor()` function for this kind of data input. The most plain implementation for the correlation in `pcdtest` is given by setting `test = "rho"` and all other statistical methods in `pcdtest` are based on the rho values.

You simply cannot test for cross-sectional dependence when the variable does not exhibit variation across time within the units.